# Problem with function in python

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python. I am trying to code a very basic function but getting errors. I dont know the reason behind it. Example code:

```
def printme( str ):
    print str;
    return;

printme("My string");
```

**This should execute logically but it gives me the following error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in "module"
NameError: name 'printme' is not defined

Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: You don't need the semicolons in Python.

Comment: Is that the exact copy and paste of your code? It gives me a indentation error on return;

Comment: is that a straight copy/paste? the `return` line isn't aligned with the `print`

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`, it's the name of a built-in type and overriding it is a Bad Idea.

Comment: No its not exact copy and paste

Comment: ricky2002: Take the hint -- **exact** cut and paste (properly indented according to the formatting rules for Stack Overflow) is essential.  Fix your question, please.

Answer (score 5):

The semicolons shouldn't be there as well as the return statement (the execution of the function ends at the last statement indented within it).

Not entirely sure how you formated the indent but python relies on that to determine scope

```
def printme(str):
    print str #This line is indented, 
              #that shows python it is an instruction in printme

printme("My string") #This line is not indented. 
                     #printme's definition ends before this
```

executes currectly

wikipedia's page on [python syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics) covers the indentation rules.

Comment: @ricky: Since Python doesn't use braces for scope, you need to have a consistent way of indenting blocks. Use either tab, or the same number of spaces every time, or Python will get confused about what block a statement belongs to.

Comment: I clarified what I meant regarding the semicolons and the indentation. Let me know if part of it still isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to follow the [python style guide (pep8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  You don't have to, but it will help avoid your indentation errors, and it will be easy to read other peoples code.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because of your indentation error. Your function never compiled so it does not exists.

*(Original question has been edited away for 'proper formatting')*

Answer (score 1):

try cp this:

```
def printme(str):
    print str

printme("My string")
```